# Saturn rings with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The planet and a ring are easily drawn.  The challenge is to layer them in such a way that the far side of the ring is hidden from view behind the planet, and the near side of the ring eclipses the planet in the foreground.  My instinct tells me that this can be done using clipping, scopes, or the backgrounds package, but I apparently lack the cleverness to turn the trick.

Here's the code for Saturn and one ring:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%Saturn on top
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=blue] (0,-.2) circle [x radius=4, y radius=1];
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle [x radius=3, y radius=.5];
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle [radius=2];
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

%ring on top
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle [radius=2];    
\draw[fill=blue] (0,-.2) circle [x radius=4, y radius=1];
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle [x radius=3, y radius=.5];    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Example with some clipping:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % red Saturn as background
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle [radius=2];
  % blue ring with white in the middle
  \draw[fill=blue, even odd rule]
    (0,-.2) circle [x radius=4, y radius=1]
    (0,0) circle [x radius=3, y radius=.5];
  % redraw red Saturn in the foreground with clipping
  \begin{scope}
    \clip[overlay] (-2.1,0) rectangle (2.1,2.1);
    \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle [radius=2];
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- Instead of filling the interior of the ring with white, the code uses option `even odd rule` for filling. The "white" interior is specified twice for filling. According to that rule, it is not filled with the fill color.

> [image: Result]

Comment: Bravo!  That's exactly what I thought could be done, but couldn't do it.  Thanks, Heiko.

Comment: That looks [strangely familiar](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=london+underground+sign).

Answer (score 18):

Another example:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,overlay-beamer-styles}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{Saturn}{2cm}{
color(0cm)=(AntiqueWhite4);
color(0.1cm)=(LightGoldenrod2);
color(0.15cm)=(Bisque1);
color(0.25cm)=(LemonChiffon3);
color(0.3cm)=(NavajoWhite3);
color(0.6cm)=(LemonChiffon3);
color(0.7cm)=(Wheat2);
color(0.85cm)=(Wheat1);
color(0.95cm)=(Bisque3);
color(1.25cm)=(Cornsilk2);
color(1.5cm)=(Bisque3);
color(1.7cm)=(AntiqueWhite3);
color(1.9cm)=(AntiqueWhite4)
}

\tikzset{satellite orbit/.style args={at pos #1 with #2}{
   postaction=decorate,
   decoration={
    markings,
    mark=
    at position #1
      with
      {
       #2
      }
    }
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=21]

\path[shading=Saturn,shading angle=21] (0,0) circle [radius=2];

\path[inner color=LemonChiffon3,outer color=Bisque3,even odd rule]
    (0,-.2) circle [x radius=4, y radius=1.25]
    (0,-.15) circle [x radius=3.8, y radius=1.2]; 

\path[inner color=Bisque2,outer color=NavajoWhite3,even odd rule]
    (0,-.15) circle [x radius=3.8, y radius=1.2]
    (0,-.15) circle [x radius=3.6, y radius=1.1]
    ;  

\path[left color=AntiqueWhite3,right color=Wheat3!98!black,even odd rule,
shading angle=31]
    (0,0) circle [x radius=3, y radius=.75]
    (0,-.15) circle [x radius=3.6, y radius=1.1];

\path[inner color=NavajoWhite2,outer color=Bisque3,even odd rule]    
    (0,0) circle [x radius=3, y radius=.75]
    (0,0) circle [x radius=2.8, y radius=.725]; 

\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.35,0.4,...,1,0,0.05,...,0.25}{
\tikzset{visibility/.style={
    shading=Saturn,
    visible on=<\xi>,
  }
}
\ifnum\xi<3
\tikzset{visibility/.append style={
    background default shade={shading=Saturn},
    background shade={right color=gray,left color=gray!80},
    shade on=<\xi>,
  }
}
\fi
\ifnum\xi>16
\tikzset{visibility/.append style={
    background default shade={shading=Saturn},
    background shade={left color=gray,right color=gray!80},
    shade on=<\xi>,
  }
}
\fi
\path[satellite orbit=%
  at pos {\x} with {%
  \node[circle,visibility]{};%
  }](0,-.2) circle [x radius=5, y radius=1.45];
}

\begin{scope}
    \clip[overlay] (-2.1,0) rectangle (2.1,2.1);
    \path[shading=Saturn,shading angle=21] (0,0) circle [radius=2];
\end{scope} 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Really cool drawing!

Comment: Amazing code, Claudio! In other news, [Houston, we have a problem...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13463320#13463320) `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: the birth of alien ducks `:)` What else will you invent? `;)`

Comment: @Claudio: my original plan was to replace the moon with the duck, but apparently I injected the duck code in the wrong place. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: oh, I may have some clues for that; let me have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Lovely, well worth an upvote or several. But this elegant picture could be even better. Shouldn't the planet's gas rings have the same aspect ratio as the moonlet rings? They're parallel to the equator too. Eclipsing the moon is very cool- but its rings are wrong too.

Comment: @EthanBolker: absolutely correct; in my defense I have to say two things: 1) I have no knowledge at all in astronomy (just picked up [this picture as a reference](http://www.astrofilitrentini.it/tnp/saturn.html)) and 2) due to scarce time at disposal, the moon lacks drawing care. But it's interesting: I'll have a try to improve the picture according to your suggestions. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the `lmodern` package for here?

Comment: And why is the last part (the top half of the planet) in a `scope` environment?

Comment: @usernumber: `lmodern` concerns the type of fonts, while the last `scope` environment is to make sure that the big planet stays in front with respect to the rear part of the ellipse that depicts the rings

Answer (score 16):

Not sure I like the colour scheme, so here's a more restrained Metapost version, featuring the useful `buildcycle` macro.

```
% prologues :=3; outputtemplate := saturn.eps; % uncomment if you want these
beginfig(1);
path globe, gap, ring[], limb[];
globe = fullcircle scaled 2cm;
gap   = fullcircle xscaled 3cm yscaled .8cm;
ring1  = fullcircle xscaled 4cm yscaled 1.2cm;
ring2  = ring1 scaled 0.93;
ring3  = ring1 scaled 0.89;
limb1 = buildcycle(subpath (5,7) of ring1, subpath (8,4) of globe);
limb2 = buildcycle(subpath (5,7) of gap, subpath (-2,6) of globe);
picture saturn; saturn = image(
fill ring1 withcolor .1red+.1green+.4white;
fill ring2 withcolor .2white;
fill ring3 withcolor .1red+.1green+.6white;
unfill gap; 
fill limb1 withcolor .2red+.1green+.7white;
fill limb2 withcolor .2red+.1green+.7white;
);
draw saturn rotated 30;
endfig;
end.  % don't include this if you are making this part of another file
```

[image]

Comment: Really cool drawing!

Comment: Impressively economical code.

Comment: I tried to learn MetaPost a bit, did not see `buildcycle` yet. You made a lot of impressive examples here. Would you like to write a MetaPost article on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org) on MetaPost which explains some clever features, motivating potential learners with such nice images? I gladly return the favor with a 500 bounty, but more important is that readers there will like it for sure and we will bring MetaPost again in a focus. You could contact me via `stefan@texblog.net` if you like.

Answer (score 15):

With PSTricks just for fun as usual. No clipping used here.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[linecolor=blue](-4,-2)(4,2)
    \pscustom*{\psellipticarcn(4,1){180}{0}\psellipticarc(0,.2)(3,.5){0}{180}}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red]{2}
    \pscustom*{\psellipticarc(4,1){180}{0}\psellipticarcn(0,.2)(3,.5){0}{180}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make it animated with an actual asteroid belt rotating :-) just saying....

Comment: @azetina: I am thinking of it.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use clipping, you can also draw semi-circles

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Top half
\fill [Wheat1] (0:1) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;

% Ring
\path[inner color=black,outer color=Cornsilk1,even odd rule]    
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.5, y radius = .25]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.7, y radius = .3]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.75, y radius = .33]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.95, y radius = .38]; 

% Bottom half
\fill [Wheat1] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe with some 3D effects you could make it look like a sphere. +1