# TikZ: rotating scope changes shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, scoping

As a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155933/saturn-rings-with-tikz), Saturn has a tilt of 26°. But when I tilt Saturn, the colors of the rings change.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=26.73]
% Top half
\fill [gray!30] (0:1) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;

% Ring
\path[inner color=black,outer color=yellow!20,even odd rule]    
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.5, y radius = .25]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.7, y radius = .3]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.75, y radius = .33]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.95, y radius = .38]; 

% Bottom half
\fill [gray!30] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get with `rotate=0` and `rotate=26.73`.

[image: without rotation]
[image: with rotation]

And what I'm trying to get
[image: goal]

How can I get the rings to rotate without changing their color? How do I rotate the shading along with the object?

I tried to add `shading angle=26.73`, but the colors are still off:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=26.73]
% Top half
\fill [gray!30] (0:1) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;

% Ring
\path[inner color=black,outer color=yellow!20, even odd rule, shading angle=26.73]    
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.5, y radius = .25]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.7, y radius = .3]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.75, y radius = .33]
    (0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.95, y radius = .38]; 

% Bottom half
\fill [gray!30] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

also results in [image: with rotation]

Comment: If you draw only the rings, for example, you will see that it is a circular shading and so, shading rotations does not change the visual (a rotate circle is a circle again :-)). So, try to use linear shadings.

Comment: @Sigur How would I go about with linear shadings to get the same aspect as in the first image?

Answer (score 4):

Is `\rotatebox` acceptable?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{26.73}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Top half
\fill [gray!30] (0:1) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;

% Ring
\path[inner color=black,outer color=yellow!20,even odd rule]    
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.5, y radius = .25]
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.7, y radius = .3]
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.75, y radius = .33]
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.95, y radius = .38]; 

% Bottom half
\fill [gray!30] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

Well, understood. You can include your entire code inside a node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Top half
\node[rotate=26.37] at (0,0) {%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [gray!30] (0:1) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;

% Ring
\path[inner color=black,outer color=yellow!20,even odd rule]    
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.5, y radius = .25]
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.7, y radius = .3]
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.75, y radius = .33]
(0, 0) circle [x radius = 1.95, y radius = .38]; 

% Bottom half
\fill [gray!30] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have other things going on in the tikzpicture that I don't want rotated, so this doesn't quite cut it

Comment: I include another solution working inside the TikZ environment, in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \tilt in {-21.6,-21.2,...,21.6,21.2,20.8,...,-21.2}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[white] (-2.3,-1.3) rectangle (2.3,1.3);
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\tilt]
      % Top half
      \fill [gray!30] (0:1) arc (0:180:1) -- cycle;
      \colorlet{yellowhite}{yellow!20!white}
      \foreach \xrad[
      evaluate={\xrad as \yrad using \xrad/5.13},
      evaluate={\xrad as \cprop using int(\xrad/2.28*100)},
      ]in {1.5,1.52,...,1.8,1.98,2.00,...,2.28} {
        \fill[fill=yellowhite!\cprop!black,even odd rule]
        (0,0 ) circle [x radius=\xrad, y radius=\yrad]
        (0,0 ) circle [x radius=\xrad+0.02,y radius=\yrad+0.02/5.13];
      }
      % Bottom half
      \fill [gray!30] (180:1) arc (180:360:1) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice Saturn :) if you create an effect 3D of the gray mass it is also more interesting. +1 for everyone.